# Generators of $\text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ group, good reference book?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Does anyone know, where I can find a reference (preferably a book) which says that the general linear group $\text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by the set

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is easy to prove without any book

Comment: I am looking just for a reference, not a proof. I don't want to include such trivial proof in a master thesis.

Comment: I am not sure but try look in S.Lang, SL(2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could cite Magnus, Karrass and Solitar's book *Combinatorial group theory*. If I were you I would cite Theorem 3.2 (p131 - this says that certain Nielsen transformations generate $F_2$) and Corollary N4 (p169 - this says that these Nielsen transformations also generate $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ in a natural way: the way you want). However, there may be other "citation paths" to this result using their book, and you may be more comfortable with one of these. Certainly - the result follows easily from the book!

Comment: Thank you. I will check this source.